# Python win32 client saving %20 instead of spaces

Tags: python, excel

I have an issue saving the pdf files. The code works to convert excel files to pdf, but it is saving all of my files with %20 instead of spaces. So "Fort Worth" would save as "Fort%20Worth".

Here is the code below. Thanks.

```
import xlwings as xw
import win32com.client

curyq = "2017Q4"

msa_list_ea = ['Albuquerque','Atlanta','Austin','Baltimore','Boston','Charlotte','Chicago','Cincinnati','Cleveland','Columbus',
        'Dallas','Dallas/Ft. Worth','Denver','Detroit','Fort Lauderdale','Fort Worth','Hartford','Houston','Indianapolis',
        'Jacksonville','Kansas City','Las Vegas','Long Island','Los Angeles','Louisville','Memphis','Miami','Milwaukee',
        'Minneapolis','Nashville','New York','Norfolk','Newark','Oakland','Orange County','Orlando','West Palm Beach',
        'Philadelphia','Phoenix','Pittsburgh','Portland','Raleigh','Richmond','Sacramento','Salt Lake City','San Antonio',
        'Riverside','San Diego','San Francisco','San Jose','Seattle','St. Louis','Tampa','Tucson','Ventura','Washington, DC']

## convert market excel EBA reports to PDF
o = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
o.Visible = False
for i in msa_list_ea:
    if i == "Dallas/Ft. Worth":
        i = "Dallas-Ft. Worth" 
    if i == "Newark":
        i = "Northern New Jersey"
    wb_path = r'G:/Team/EBAs/{}/Excel/{}_EBA_{}.xlsx'.format(curyq, i, curyq)

    wb = o.Workbooks.Open(wb_path)

    ws_index_list = [1] #chooses which sheet in workbook to print (counting begins at 1)

    path_to_pdf = r'G:/Team/EBAs/{}/PDF/{}_EBA_{}.pdf'.format(curyq, i, curyq) ## path to save pdf file

    wb.WorkSheets(ws_index_list).Select()

    wb.ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, path_to_pdf)
    wb.Close(False)
    print("{}".format(i))
```

Comment: This must have something to do with an html format. 20 is hex for 32 dec and ascii 32 is the space character. Typically, %20 is used to replace spaces in urls.

Comment: Is it possible to convert the filename out of the html format when I save the pdf?

Answer (score 1):

This prints correctly in my terminal, no `%20`s here.

I assume your **raw string literal** is not respected by the external call to Excel in `wb.ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, path_to_pdf)`.

Try adding quotes:

```
path_to_pdf = r'"G:/Team/EBAs/{}/PDF/{}_EBA_{}.pdf"'.format(curyq, i, curyq) ## path to save pdf file
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when running a similar code on a Windows machine. The path was using forward slashes. Using double backslashes solved the problem.

To make it non OS specific I used the os and pathlib modules to format the path correctly:

```
path_to_pdf = os.fspath(Path(path_to_pdf))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the shutil library's move method to auto rename in Python code.

```
import shutil
corruptedFilename = outputPdfFile.replace(' ','%20')
shutil.move(corruptedFilename , outputPdfFile)
```

We could have also used os.rename for the above task. But then we need to give it as follows:-

```
os.rename(os.rename('path/to/file.txt', 'path/to/new/directory/file.txt')
```

The subtle difference between shutil.move method and os.rename is shutil.move can also be used to move file into a new directory or rename a file whereas os.rename can only be used to rename a particular file into a new directory. And it doesn't work across disk drives. More information here

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-shutil-move-method/

https://python.omics.wiki/file-operations/file-commands/os-rename-vs-shutil-move

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).